# Problem installing Laravel Password in Laravel 10

Tags: php, laravel, installation, laravel-10

when I can install Laravel password, I got this error, what exactly should I do to solve this problem, if you can help me step by step to solve the problem

```
 composer require laravel/passport
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 6 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Could not resolve host: repo.packagist.org), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update laravel/passport
Loading composer repositories with package information
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 6 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Could not resolve host: repo.packagist.org), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - laravel/passport[v11.5.0, ..., v11.8.4] require league/oauth2-server ^8.2 -> satisfiable by league/oauth2-server[8.2.0, ..., 8.5.3].
    - laravel/passport[v11.8.5, ..., v11.8.8] require lcobucci/jwt ^4.3|^5.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.3.0, 5.0.0].
    - league/oauth2-server[8.5.2, ..., 8.5.3] require lcobucci/jwt ^4.3 || ^5.0 -> satisfiable by lcobucci/jwt[4.3.0, 5.0.0].
    - laravel/passport[v0.1.0, ..., v0.2.4, v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.18, v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.11, v3.0.0, ..., v3.0.2, v4.0.0, ..., v4.0.3, v5.0.0, ..., v5.0.3, v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.7, v7.0.0, ..., v7.5.1] require guzzlehttp/guzzle ~6.0 -> found guzzlehttp/guzzle[6.0.0, ..., 6.5.8] but it conflicts with your root composer.json require (^7.2).
    - laravel/passport[v8.0.0, ..., v8.5.0, v9.0.0, ..., v9.3.2] require php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.2.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/passport v9.4.0 requires illuminate/auth ^6.18.31|^7.22.4 -> found illuminate/auth[v6.18.31, ..., v6.20.44, v7.22.4, ..., v7.30.6] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/passport[v10.0.0, ..., v10.0.1] require php ^7.3 -> your php version (8.2.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - laravel/passport[v10.1.0, ..., v10.2.2] require illuminate/auth ^8.2 -> found illuminate/auth[v8.2.0, ..., v8.83.27] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/passport[v10.3.0, ..., v10.3.2] require illuminate/auth ^8.2|^9.0 -> found illuminate/auth[v8.2.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.15] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/passport[v10.3.3, ..., v10.4.2] require illuminate/auth ^8.37|^9.0 -> found illuminate/auth[v8.37.0, ..., v8.83.27, v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.15] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - laravel/passport[v11.0.0, ..., v11.4.0] require illuminate/auth ^9.0 -> found illuminate/auth[v9.0.0, ..., v9.52.15] but these were not loaded, likely because it conflicts with another require.
    - league/oauth2-server[8.2.0, ..., 8.5.1] require psr/http-message ^1.0.1 -> found psr/http-message[1.0.1, 1.1] but the package is fixed to 2.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - lcobucci/jwt[4.3.0, 5.0.0] require ext-sodium * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's sodium extension.
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/passport * -> satisfiable by laravel/passport[v0.1.0, ..., v0.2.4, v1.0.0, ..., v1.0.18, v2.0.0, ..., v2.0.11, v3.0.0, v3.0.1, v3.0.2, v4.0.0, v4.0.1, v4.0.2, v4.0.3, v5.0.0, v5.0.1, v5.0.2, v5.0.3, v6.0.0, ..., v6.0.7, v7.0.0, ..., v7.5.1, v8.0.0, ..., v8.5.0, v9.0.0, ..., v9.4.0, v10.0.0, ..., v10.4.2, v11.0.0, ..., v11.8.8].

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - F:\xampp\php\php.ini
You can also run `php --ini` in a terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
Alternatively, you can run Composer with `--ignore-platform-req=ext-sodium` to temporarily ignore these required extensions.

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require laravel/passport:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require laravel/passport:^2.1" if you know which you need.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.
```

I use Windows 10 and xampp or the following specifications:
Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.2.0
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 8.2.0
PHP extension: mysqli Documentation curl Documentation mbstring Documentation
PHP version: 8.2.0

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXNa0.jpg)

Please help me to solve this problem if you can

Comment: as it says in the error `require ext-sodium` you need to install the php extension sodium

Comment: I ran the following command and my problem was solved
composer requires laravel/passport --with-all-dependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can uncomment the "sodium" extension in the php.ini file

Comment: I ran the following command and my problem was solved
composer requires laravel/passport --with-all-dependencies